# php curl or file_get_contents too slow on hosted site

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I'm using `cUrl` to get the file's contents of the same website's page, and writing to another file ( To convert dynamic php file into static php file for menu caching purpose )

```
$dynamic = 'http://mysite.in/menu.php';
$static = "../menu-static.php" ;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$dynamic);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$file = curl_exec($ch);

file_put_contents($static, $file);
die();
```

It works perfect on localhost. But taking **too much** time when it is running on hosted website, and at last even the output file (`$static = "../menu-static.php"`) is empty.

I can't determine where is the problem .. Please help

I've also tried `file_get_contents` instead of `cUrl` with no luck ..

Comment: no error handling. what did you expect?

Comment: This is dangerous. Your web server process should never have write access to the files it serves. Consider something like [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) in reverse proxy mode to cache your content.

Comment: The code is loading for sometime and at the end, output file (`$static = "../menu-static.php"`) is generating but its empty .

Comment: @AlexHowansky I'm looking for a handy solution since i'm only using caching for menu only.. no other extra functionality required..

Comment: That doesn't make it any less dangerous. Memcache might be good for you. Or have a cron job (under a different userid) that runs periodically to generate the output file.

Comment: I've made this option under a secured control panel page ..

Comment: If your web server process has write access to DOCUMENT_ROOT then all pages are vulnerable, regardless of which one of them you're actually using the feature on.

Comment: @AlexHowansky .. Can you please explain with example scenario .. ?

Comment: The basic idea is that the web server shouldn't be able to change the files it's serving. I can't give you a specific example vulnerability because there is no one definitive case, it's going to vary from server to server and from app to app. So, making the DOCUMENT_ROOT read-only is simply best practice when securing a server. See [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20105/why-shouldnt-var-www-have-chmod-777) for good explanations.